# On woocommerce how do I remove this cropping to product catergory thumbnails?

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, thumbnails

I've searched and tried fixing this myself for several hours, however, I cannot find a proper solution.

The images I upload to Woocommerce's product category are getting cropped to a 1:1 aspect ratio, and I want them to stay at the original dimensions and aspect ratio that I uploaded them at.

the main part of the snippet I am confused with is that there is an added -150x150.png at the end of my img src. How in the world do I remove that? I could not find it anywhere in any of the woocommerce php files. I'm assuming this is being added when the thumbnail is uploaded?

The code that the php creates to display the image looks like this:

```
<a href="http://localhost/radioactivewonderland/?product_cat=phone-charms">

    <img src="http://localhost/radioactivewonderland/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/cghjnfgchjn-150x150.png" alt="Phone Charms" height="" width="Phone Charms" />      




    <h3> Phone Charms <mark class="count">(1)</mark>        </h3>


</a>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update for WooCommerce 3.4

The thumbnail sizes are now available in the Customizer. You'll need to open the Customizer, then select WooCommerce, then Product Images.

[image: Customizer>WooCommerce>Product Images]

The "main image" is the single product image. And the "thumbnail" is the shop/archive loop image.

The settings are no longer available in the admin Settings.

---

The category images are the same size as `shop_image` (or Catalog) thumbnail.  WooCommerce handles its product thumbnails in its settings:

WooCommerce->Settings>Products>Display

You can change its height, width, and toggle the hard crop on/off.

[image: WooCommerce product image settings]

After changing the image sizes you will need to [regenerate thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/).

Comment: TYTYTY! I just totally skimmed over the Display tab on the Products page(it was the hard crop box that made everything go to hell) I also had to use the plugin regenerate thumbnails to actually make the change occur for anyone else reading this in the future. I'm good with coding, however, I'm new to wordpress so thank you for the help :) I'll make sure to return the favor you gave me to others in the community :D

Comment: You're welcome! And paying it forward is what WordPress is all about, imo.

Comment: @helgatheviking can you please add to your answer the part in the comment of Chris Haugen where he says to install [this plugin (Regenerate Thumbnails)](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) after doing the steps you specified? This last part (in conjunction with your explanation) was the definitive solution for me. Thank you!

Comment: Woocommerce does no longer have a display section in Settings > Products as of now

Comment: @martinschwartz I believe it's in the Customizer now.

Comment: @martinschwartz updated. I *think* it's as of WooCommerce 3.4, but if it was 3.3, feel free to edit.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, go to Theme `Options> Shop settings`, and set `Enable Product Image Crop on Catalog pages` to `OFF`.

Then navigate to `Appearance> customize> WooCommerce> Product images`, and set `Thumbnail cropping` to `uncropped.`

Save the settings, and view your shop page out of the customizer. Your full images should display.

Let me know if that works for you.